# Still struggling with Isotope hide/reveal plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to implement David DeSandro's [hide/reveal plugin](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/drpJK/) for Isotope and cannot get it to work. `display:none` is still being written to the items filtered out and the scale transition is still happening. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Edit: I fixed my bindings, but still cannot stop filtered items disappearing.

Here's the code I'm using for isotope:

```
    // Grab initial filter if there's a hash on the URL
    var initialFilter = window.location.hash && ( '.' + window.location.hash.substr(1) ) || '*';

    // Initialize Isotope
    var $container = $('#iso-loop').imagesLoaded( function () {
        $container.fadeIn().isotope({
            itemSelector : '.iso-post',
            layoutMode : iso_vars.iso_layout,
            filter : initialFilter,
            hiddenStyle: {
              opacity: 0.5
            },
            visibleStyle: {
              opacity: 1
            },          
        });
    });

    // bind filter button click
    $('#filters').on( 'click', 'a', function() {
      var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
      $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
    });
```

It does exactly what Isotope default filter normally does -- filtered items disappear, although I think I see the new hiddenStyle opacity being implemented before they disappear.

So how to stop them disappearing?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible. The snippet you posted binds that function to `button` *elements* only, within the element with id `filters`.

For it to match the class of an element it would have to start with a dor, i.e. `.button`.

Comment: I've tried it with class as a selector and tag as a selector. In fact I've replicated the entire structure of the CodePen example and it still doesn't work. Could the problem be that my filters and elements are created dynamically (in my case pulling posts and categories from within Wordpress)?

Comment: It's very hard to speculate without seeing the code. There's a general request on stack overflow to provide an mcve http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - if you can do that you're much more likely to get a solution

Comment: I'm trying to incorporate it into this isotope plugin [link](https://github.com/mandiwise/isotope-posts) but it uses hash anchors in the filters, which complicates matters. I can post the basic script in a new Answer if needed